# C++ - is a pointer to a single value same as a size 1 dynamic array?

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I have this snippet of code which I am considering to simplfy:

```
if (numberOfResults > 1)
{

    trackResult_ = new TrackResult[numberOfResults];
    for (int i=0; i < numberOfResults; i++)
        {
            // Make a deep copy
            TrackResult tempResult = result[i];
            TrackResult * clone  = new TrackResult(tempResult);
            trackResult_[i]  = *clone;
        }

    storeJointResults(trackResult_, numberOfResults);
}
else
{
    trackResult_ = new TrackResult(*result);
}
```

(I have 'no choice' but to use a simple dynamic array here. Vectors are deemed 'too complicated' at my workplace)

I am wondering if I can get away with

```
// even if we just have one result, we init an array size of one
trackResult_ = new TrackResult[numberOfResults];
```

However, I have in several points check for the number of results and act accordingly

```
if (numberOfResults_ == 1)
{
   velocity = trackResult_.velocity;
}
```

Would those code still work? If not, why?

Comment: Just curious, how do you delete trackResult_ in the first code sample?

Comment: if (trackResult_ == 1) delete trackResult_;
 else if (trackResult_ > 1) delete trackResult_[];

Comment: This code is awful. You should start a campaign at your workplace to allow the use of productivity-boosters such as vectors.

Comment: Mistake... if (numebrOfResult_ > 1) ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The array of size 1 does not need to be a special case.

When you allocate a dynamic array you are given a pointer to the first element.  If the array is of size 1, this is pretty much indistinguishable from just having allocated a single instance of the object.

Your special case usage would work if you changed the . to an ->
However I'd recommend not special-casing it and just use trackResult_[0].velocity

Comment: Note that you must use delete[] not simply delete on dynamically allocated arrays (even if it is of size one)

Answer (score 3):

No, you need to ensure you match the correct scalar `delete` or array `delete[]` depending on whether you say `new TrackResult[n];` or `new TrackResult;`.

Also, this leaks memory for each loop iteration:

```
 TrackResult tempResult = result[i];
 TrackResult * clone  = new TrackResult(tempResult);
 TrackResult_[i]  = *clone;
```

Comment: That leaky "deep copy" should just be `trackResult_[i] = result[i];`. It would be even better to persuade the workplace that using standard containers, and replacing this whole mess with `trackResult_ = result;`, is not "too complicated".

Answer (score 3):

How are vectors too complicated? If anything, the simplify your code.

Comment: I have no idea. It's my supervisor who whack at me for using vectors. Making the problem worse is that his code does not use std containers. He was concerned about speed.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Alex, using the . operator on a pointer is not my recommended style either, so those other points ought to be changed anyhow, and thus not discourage you from simplifying the piece of code you mention.